# React Redux Thunk actions with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to understand what will be the suitable type that returns from my actions functions:
(the structure of the actions functions that split into two functions is intentional)

type.ts:

```ts
export interface JsxActions {
  init: (params: IProject, filterSearch ? : ISearch[]) => any;
}

export interface ApiFunc {
  initCostDashboard: (params: IProject, filterSearch ? : ISearch[]) => any;
}
```

actions.ts:

```ts
export let jsxActions: JsxActions | Partial < JsxActions > = {};

jsxActions.init = function(params: IProject, filterSearch ? : ISearch[]): /* What will be return type */ {
  return function(dispatch: Dispatch < AppActions > , getState: () => AppState) {
    return api.initCostDashboard(params, filterSearch)(dispatch, getState);
  };
};

export let api = {}
as ApiFunc;
api.initCostDashboard = function(params: IProject, filterSearch ? : ISearch[]) /* What will be return type */ {
  return function(dispatch: Dispatch < AppActions > , getState: () => AppState) {
    // ...Do something
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to look at https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-redux-thunks to understand how to be explicit about the return type of init and initCostDashboard, which return ThunkActions.